# Using arrow -> and dot . operators together in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I was under the impression that it was possible to access data from a sub-node of a linked list or similar structure by using the arrow and dot operators together like so:

```
typedef struct a{
int num;
struct a *left;
struct a *right;
}tree;

tree *sample;
...
if(sample->left.num > sample->right.num)
    //do something
```

but when I try to implement this, using -> and . to access data from a sub node I get the error "request for member num in something not a structure or union".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `->` for pointers; use `.` for objects.

In your specific case you want

```
if (sample->left->num > sample->right->num)
```

because all of `sample`, `sample->left`, and `sample->right` are pointers.

If you convert any of those pointers in the pointed to object; use `.` instead

```
struct a copyright;
copyright = *(sample->right);
// if (sample->left->num > copyright.num)
if (*(sample->left).num > copyright.num)
```

Answer (score 24):

Since I don't see it mentioned explicitly:

- Use -> to *dereference the pointer* on its left hand side and access the member on its right hand side.
- Use . to access the member on its right hand side of *the variable* on its left hand side.

Comment: I googled "c arrow vs dot operator" and landed here. Assuming this is accurate, it's the most clear and succinct description I found. If someone with more C knowledge could confirm or deny this, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

. is for accessing the members of a struct (or union) e.g.

```
struct S {
int x;
}

S test;
test.x;
```

-> is a shorter way to write (*pointer_to_struct).struct_member

Answer (score 5):

sample->left gives a `struct a*`, not a `struct a`, so we're dealing with pointers.
So you still have to use `->`.

You can, however, use `sample->left->num`.

Answer (score 0):

`sample->left` and `sample->right` are also pointers, so you want:

```
if (sample->left->num > sample->right->num) {
    // do something
}
```